# Remove Array Elements Based on Key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
array(
  '1' => red,
  '2' => green,
  '3' => blue,
  '4' => orange
);
```

And a second array:

```
array(
  '0' => 1,
  '1' => 4
);
```

I want to keep only those elements in Array 1 that have a key value equal to a value in Array 2.

So the final array should look like:

```
array (
    '1' => red,
    '4' => orange
);
```

Comment: What have you tried? We are happy to help you fix problems in your existing code, but we will not (in most cases) write the code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to get the values that share keys (after using [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) on the 2nd array).

```
$array3 = array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2));
```

Comment: This will not preserve the values from $array1. The result is `Array ( [1] => 0 [4] => 1 )`.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: I fixed it.  I had the parameters reversed.  It works correctly now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use array_intersect_key with array_flip,

```
$r = array_intersect_key($a, array_flip($b));
```